# ORMLite get parent foreign object

Tags: android, ormlite

I have two  objects that are related:

User -> Comments

One user can have multiple comments.  When I query a comment using dao.queryById(id), I am able to get the Comment, but the User field is set to a null reference.  My user field has the following in the comment class:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "user_id")
public User User;
```

I extracted the database from the emulator and confirmed that the foreign key is properly referenced to the parent user.  The relationships are working good.

Only issue is that the parent foreign object (User) is not being retrieved along with the child (Comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you set `foreignAutoRefresh = true` for the Database field.

http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-auto-refresh

Comment: I did try, however, after the database and tables has already been created.  Will I need to delete the tables and recreate them for this to take effect?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. What you can test  is calling `commentDao.refresh(comment)` and then see if the `User` object is filled.

Comment: thanks @super-qua!  I'll give that a try tonight and let you know.

Comment: Ok nice. I'm curious about it

Comment: Yes it automatically worked.  I must've done something wrong when I attempted it; it was middle of the night. Thanks for the help bud.